# Migrate Promoted links from SP 2013 to SPO Modern Page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, csom, promoted-links

I would need some suggestion regarding the migration of promoted links. I have promoted links in SP 2013 and i need to migrate the promoted link to SPO modern page.

How can this be done via program (csom) or manually migrate. Well manual migrate gotta be the last option.

Any suggestion would be appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The promoted links web part does not exist for modern pages. Instead, consider using the new Hero web part. The UI is updated, and users often find it much easier to configure than the old promoted links list/web part.

Comment: What would it make an difference between quick links and Hero, foremost i would want to migrate from SP 2013 to SPO modern page with matching properties using csom

Comment: Certainly, both can display links. It's up to you as to which UI you prefer. Though, MS doesn't have good documentation how to provision modern web parts with csom, afaik. One sample is here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages

Comment: Well i have found github spfx which would help us to interact with promoted links, eventually not an exact match but similar after i'm quite confused how to match the properties from SP 2013 to spfx.
https://github.com/CloudDesignBox/cdb-promoted-links

Comment: Or how about using the Sharegate ? would that be an great idea.

Comment: ShareGate is usually a great idea, but it lacks the ability to convert classic parts (promoted links) to modern parts. That will require manual effort or code.

Comment: Well how to prefer to use the code since i have no clue to match the properties.

Comment: MS didn't make it easy, and again, docs are poor. This page has a decent guide on how to get started, but again, don't expect this to go smoothly: https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2017/03/provisioning-modern-pages-and-spfx-web-parts.html

Comment: Thank you, that's great ! I will try and hope this works which haven't tried migrating promoted links. Fingers crossed